# With XTK, can we generate an MPR slice in any position and orientation through the 3D volume

Tags: xtk

Xtk provide an MPR slice in x,y and z position.
I would to know if  we can generate an MPR slice in any position and orientation through the 3D volume Best,AMAL

Answer (score 0):

you can access the image volume like this volume.image but arbitrary reslicing is not implemented yet

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: yes, it answers the question since arbitrary reslicing was requested by the poster and it is possible to implement on top of volume.image